# Matlab pseudocode for data splitting

Tags: matlab, for-loop, pseudocode

A pseudocode for the data split implementation:
     inds= 1...n; // divide randomly to N slots
      for k=1...N 
            n(k)= round(n/(N-k+1)); // size of this chunk
            n= n-n(k); // number of samples left to divide later…
            slotInds(k)= chooseNfromSet(inds, n(k)); // chooses n(k) samples from inds!
            inds= setdifference(inds, slotInds(k)); //  samples left to divide later…
     end
     assert: sum(k=1...5, n(k)) == N // this should hold true now!

```
chooseNfromSet(inds,n) ==  
    randsample(inds,n) % in matlab
```

#

My response to the pseudocode above in Matlab is:

```
inds=1:n;
    for k=1:N
        n(k)= round(n/(N-k+1));   
        n= n-n(k);  
        slotInds(k)= randsample(inds,n); 
        inds= setdifference(inds, slotInds(k)); 
    end
```

#

However there is error

```
In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
```

and i cant understand the last line of pseudocode

```
assert: sum(k=1...5, n(k)) == N
```

Comment: At least for the assert, it is saying the sum of the elements of K (which contains the numbers 1 through 5) and the elements in the array n in the indices from 1 to 5 are equal to whatever integer N is.  For the first part of your question, is there any code you are leaving out from what you have shown here?

Comment: X= [ones(n,1),data(:,1:(end-1))]; global X; 
y= data(:,end); global y; 
m= size(X,2); % number of prediction features (wine quality not counted!)  

Iin= randsample(I0,round(n*4/5)); % just one teaching set...
Iout= setdiff(I0,Iin);  
f= @(beta)(g(beta,Iin)); % a function of one argument beta to be minimized! 
beta0= zeros(m,1);  #############this was for one set to generate insample and out sample error but replacing it with for loop with 5 iteration to generate new in sample and out sample error

Comment: Iin= randsample(I0,round(n*4/5)) is insample error and Iout= setdiff(I0,Iin); is out sample error for one teaching set. The function is same  f= @(beta)(g(beta,Iin));

Comment: In the line `slotInds(k)=randsample(inds,n);` the right-hand-side is an `n`-length vector, which you are trying to assign to a single array element, `slotInds(k)`. This is exactly what your error is trying to tell you.